# Example of non homotopic maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We know that a space $X$ is contractible iff for any space $Y$ and for any two maps (continuous) $f,g:Y \to X$ we have that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic. We also know that the unit circle $S^1$ is not contractible so there must be a space $Y$ and two non homotopic maps $f$ and $g$ from $Y$ to $S^1$. I know it seems simple but I am new to the subject and I could not come up with an example of $Y$,$f$ and $g$ as above!

(note that I am talking about homotopy of maps not homotpy of paths)

Comment: Take $Y=S^{1}$, $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=1$.

Comment: As is turns out, for nice spaces $Y$ there is a group isomorphism $[Y,S^1]\cong H^1(Y;\mathbb{Z})$. In particular, any CW complex with non-trivial first singular homology admits non-homotopically trivial maps into $S^1$. The easiest example is to take $Y=S^1$. Then $[S^1,S^1]\cong H^1S^1\cong \mathbb{Z}$. The elements of this group are represented by the maps $\varphi_n:z\mapsto z^n$. In particular, if $m\neq n$, then $\varphi_m\not\simeq\varphi_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Just take $Y=S^1$, $f=\operatorname{id}$ and $g=\operatorname{const}_p$, where the latter denotes the constant map with value an arbitrary point $p\in S^1$.

By the way: These are paths in $S^1$, but paths are functions so if you want some example of non-homotopic functions you are perfectly allowed to take non-homotopic paths.